# Asychronous Image Upload in a Form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So I have this form that needs to be filled out by the user.  In the form, there is a place to upload an image.  Currently, the upload takes place when the user hits "Submit" at the end of the form, however, that causes an up to 30 second delay (due to image size).

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to start that upload while the user is still filling out the form, rather than selecting the image, finishing the form, then uploading it.  (This way it really cuts down on the time needed, per form)

The form itself already has a dozen other things it's doing to submit the information to the database and such, so i've been looking into using javascript with an onchange event to get into the javascript, and perhaps from there moving back into php to perform the upload, all while not reloading the page.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: have you consider putting this image upload in a queue?

Comment: Could you elaborate?  There is only 1 image per form (page) and I'm really just looking to do the upload while the user is finishing the form.

Comment: hum, then you can upload the image using something like swfupload http://swfupload.org/

Comment: look this http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really aren't many ways, the most common one is to use an iframe.  Something along the lines of: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 0):

This has worked very well for me:

[jQUploader](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php)